# Remove the leading zero in time in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How to remove the Leading zeros in time.
For eg: 09:04, I want it should be 9:04

But googling the issue doesn't give me anything. 
Do you have any idea please?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Right Click -> Format Cell with `h:mm`

[image]

**See Also : [Format numbers as dates or times](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Format-numbers-as-dates-or-times-418bd3fe-0577-47c8-8caa-b4d30c528309?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ)**

Comment: I tried but its not working..giving same results 09:04.

Comment: For minutes and seconds, this would be `m:ss`. If it's not on the list, it's possible to add it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Format the cell; right-click in the required cell and select 'Format Cells'

On the Number tab select the category 'Custom'.

It is likely that the format for the time is hh:mm. In the 'Type;' box change this to h:mm and then click OK.

I hope that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter how you format it, they seem to stay, however, copying the date column to another sheet and saving it as a csv seems to remove them.